# Legend not dispalyed

Tags: matplotlib, legend, title

I am  trying to draw a simple graph in python using matplotlib.I am not able to use pyplot.legend() method to display legend.Please help me.

I looked on the net and found a simple code which says it works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate random data for plotting
x = np.linspace(0.0,100,50)
y = np.random.normal(size=50)

plt.plot(x,y)

# call method plt.legend
plt.legend(['line plot 1'])

plt.show()
```

from the site 
http://queirozf.com/entries/matplotlib-examples-displaying-and-configuring-legends.

My code is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
views = [123,56,64,54,223,5523]
days = range(1,7)
plt.xlabel("Days")
plt.ylabel("Views")
plt.title("You Tube views")
plt.legend(["Youtube views"])
plt.plot(days,views)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Write ***plt.legend(["Youtube views"])*** next ***plt.plot(days,views)***

```
plt.xlabel("Days")
plt.ylabel("Views")
plt.title("You Tube views")
plt.plot(days,views)
plt.legend(["Youtube views"])
plt.show()
```